# Could not install cordova phonegap-push-plugin for my ionic 3 app

Tags: android, ios, plugins, push, phonegap

I've tried to install on mac for my ionic 3 app the push plugin.

In order to install I run: **sudo ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push**

As a result I get:

-for Android seems ok

-for iOS I recive the following errors:

```
Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for ios
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push': Error 
at copyNewFile (/Users/macbook/ionic/push2018-2/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/plugman/pluginHandlers.js:346:45)
at installHelper (/Users/macbook/ionic/push2018-2/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/plugman/pluginHandlers.js:269:13)
at install (/Users/macbook/ionic/push2018-2/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/plugman/pluginHandlers.js:35:13)
at ActionStack.process (/Users/macbook/ionic/push2018-2/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ActionStack.js:56:25)
at PluginManager.doOperation (/Users/macbook/ionic/push2018-2/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/PluginManager.js:114:20)
at PluginManager.addPlugin (/Users/macbook/ionic/push2018-2/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/PluginManager.js:144:17)
at Api.addPlugin (/Users/macbook/ionic/push2018-2/platforms/ios/cordova/Api.js:234:10)
at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:594:10)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:357:28
at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)

Error: Uh oh!
"/Users/macbook/ionic/push2018-2/platforms/ios/push2018-2/Plugins/phonegap-plugin-
push/AppDelegate+notification.m" already exists!

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --save (exit code 1).
```

===========================================================

My technologies:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

Global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

Local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8

Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4

Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.0 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
Node       : v7.3.0
npm        : 3.10.10 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b 

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods.rb
```

Any idea about what causes this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. In case it helps someone: I've installed the phonegap-plugin-push without "sudo" in command.

Answer (score 0):

Check  if u have the lasted cordova version , and if your version supports the plugin, check here may help [phonegap-plugin-push Issues](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/610)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've already checkd and the version I use supports the plugin.

Comment: try do install it again its says on your log file "/Users/macbook/ionic/push2018-2/platforms/ios/push2018-2/Plugins/phonegap-plugin-
push/AppDelegate+notification.m already exists!"  cordova plugin rm phonegap-plugin-push@1.8.1 and cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push@1.8.1